# Получение пути картинки из MySql и вставка в Blade

Tags: php, html, laravel, blade

Необходимо для конкретного id новости получать соответствующий путь пикчи из БД. Насколько я знаю вставка картинок сама по себе делается так :

```
{{asset('images/image.jpg')}}
```

А адрес своей картинки из БД я получаю так :

```
{{$playerprofile->playerphoto}}
```

Как мне это "состыковать"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(нормальный вариант)**

Использовать тег img и в путь помещать данные из БД

```
<img src="{{$playerprofile->playerphoto}}" alt="">
```

**(плохой вариант)**

Если именно "состыковать", есть вариант вставить промежуточное

```
<?php
 $image = $playerprofile->playerphoto; ?>
```

{{asset($image)}}

Comment: Ну я как раз делал как в первом варианте. Но немного намудрил с путями, т.к. думал, что если не использовать asset(), то к пути будет добавляться адрес текущей страницы.